# as Tom told him not to

Tags: meaning, negation, ellipsis

Can sentences a, b and c be used instead of sentences a1, b1 and c1?

a. He didn't turn off the lights, as Tom told him to.

b. He didn't turn off the lights, since Tom told him to.

c. He didn't turn off the lights, because Tom told him to.

=====================

a1. He didn't turn off the lights, as Tom told him **not** to.

b1. He didn't turn off the lights, since Tom told him **not** to.

c1. He didn't turn off the lights, because Tom told him **not** to.

I am not sure the first three work with that meaning. To me, they seem to be saying that he wanted to go against Tom's will and as Tom told him to turn off the lights, he decided not to.

But maybe the first three could be used in that way if context allowed it.

Comment: As a native speaker, I think the most natural way to express this is "He left the lights on, [as/since/because] Tom told him to." By using a positive action (leave on) instead of a negative one (don't turn off), you can avoid having to repeat the negation (which in my opinion sounds a little awkward).

Answer (score 3):

I think the omitted part of the sentence as:

> He didn't turn off the lights, as Tom told him **to turn off the lights.**

My inference: He didn't like that Tom gave him the instruction, so he determined not to turn off the light.

> He didn't turn off the lights, as Tom told him **not to turn off the lights.**

My inference: He just followed Tom's instruction.

Obviously, both are different.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the first three sentences definitely carry the implication that he was going against Tom's instructions; (b) and (c) imply that it was deliberate. "Tom told him to" would be understood to mean "...turn off the lights".

However, you could turn the sentence round and say

> As Tom had told him, he didn't turn off the lights.

which does imply that *not* doing so was following Tom's instructions.

Comment: Thank you so much, Kate, for your reply, which is, as usual, very precise and to the point. Would you say the same of: "He didn't turn off the lights, as/since/because he was told to." I don't think putting the phrase in passive changes anything.  Would you agree?

Comment: No, making the sentence passive doesn't change anything. _Told to_ means _told to do it_. Your sentence requires _told not to_.

Answer (score 1):

No. Sentences a, b and c are ambiguous, and could mean either that he did what Tom told him to do, or he went against Tom's will. Without a clarifying context, the most common reaction would be confusion.

On the other hand, sentences a1, b1, and c1, are perfectly clear, so you couldn't use a, b or c in their place.

Comment: Non-native speakers like us form sentences based on the rules we learnt, which often leads to some unnatural sentences. Initially we wouldn't have the instinct to know the sentence is ambiguous or not.

Comment: Can you give an example for the ambiguity? Do the listeners consider the sentence as "He didn't turn off the lights, as Tom told him **to do so.** ?